# How come sometimes I can't issue any orders or even change weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Sometimes the menu that comes up when I hold the left-shift key is completely non-functional.  My abilities are off cooldown, and indeed work just fine if I trigger them using hotkeys.  But I can't trigger them off the shift menu, nor can I tell me allies to use abilities or even get the weapon selection UI to come up.  One I reach this state, I seem to stay in it permanently.  I usually end up reloading a saved game and then it works again.

Is this an in-game effect, or a bug?  In either case, what triggers it and is there any way out of it short of a reload?

Comment: I take it your allies don't have "blocked" over their abilities?

Comment: It has happened to me a few times too, and reloading has always fixed it for me as well. 99% sure it's a glitch. Haven't been able to nail down a cause, though.

Comment: @MBraedley No, and it is blocking my own abilities too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. It has happened to me before too. No one knows what causes it, because Mass Effect 3 is closed source. If you want to file a bug report you can do so at the bioware forums, accessible through social.bioware.com. There it will be forwarded on to the developers, and your problem has a very good chance of being solved. I'm personally not surprised that there are some bugs in the game, as it is still relatively new.